# Proving an inequality with a given contraint

Tags: inequality

I found an inequality and I have been stuck for days trying to solve it. I tried everything but nothing I try seems to work. The inequality is:

given $a,b,c{\gt}0$ and that  $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$

prove that  ${ab\over c}+{ac\over b}+{bc\over a}{\ge}3$

Can somebody please tell me how this to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add the working from you few days trying to solve it, by editing your post to include them.

Comment: Doesn't hold for $\,a=b=c=-1\,$. If the question assumes $\,a,b,c \gt 0\,$ then it should state so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a,b,c$ are positive, it is enough to show the homogeneous:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{ab}{c}\right)^2 \geqslant 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

$$\iff (a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)^2\geqslant 3(abc)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

With $x=a^2, y=b^2, z=c^2$, this is the same as
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2 \geqslant x^2yz+y^2zx+x^2zy$$
which is true by Muirhead or Rearrangement.

Comment: May be worth noting that both you and (presumably) the OP are assuming positive $\,a,b,c\,$.